# Unsure as to proper translation

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, inscription

[image: Image of inscription]

I am not sure as to the proper translation of the above inscription:

> Si tibi quos patria et virtus lape maxima fasces tradidit exilio perdidit invidia / at tua non odium non mors non tempora possunt perdere quae reparat nomina clara nepos.

The second part seems more straightforward, perhaps being something along the lines of

> ...but neither your hate nor death nor time can erase the clear names which the descendant renews.

How should I take the first part? It appears to say something about bundles, virtue, bequeathing, jealousy, and destruction, but I can't seem to nail down the syntax. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Total noob here. He was exiled according to the wikipedia entry for "Lapo da Castiglionchio" so something along the lines of "delivered into exile and destroyed by envy". The first few words dealing with country and virtue (basic translation) but likely a way of eulogizing the deceased (Lapa Maxima Faces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe reordering the syntax in a more English-like structure might help:

> Lape, si invidia exsilio perdidit fasces quos patria et maxima virtus tibi tradidit (= tradiderunt), at non odium, non mors, non tempora possunt perdere tua clara nomina, quae nepos reparat.

(Some Googling indicates that the Lapus in question is [this guy](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapo_da_Castiglionchio).)

Comment: And *fasces* = political power, public offices. (By the way, it took me a while to understand that the text addresses someone called Lapus. That was the crucial information for me.)